# MFMailComposeViewController iOS 4.0

Tags: iphone, ios4, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

When sending an email with a picture attachment in iOS4, the last step asks if you want to reduce the message size by scaling the image. Is it possible to force the app to send the highest resolution image and not to display this message?

Comment: Don't think that behavior can be altered. You can look at [MailCore](http://www.mronge.com/m/MailCore/API/) if you want to circumvent.